# When I get the same val_loss and val_accuracy after X epochs or 100X epochs- is there a difference?

Tags: neural-networks

For example:

A. After 2 epochs val_loss is 0.4 and val_acc is 0.85

B. After 600 epochs I get to the same values.

Further details:

1. Training set size is above 200K images (above 100K for each class, balanced). Validation is about 15k and balanced. 2 classes.
2. Training acc reaches 0.99 and training loss reaches 0.1
3. Batch is 32 for both while the learning rate is 1e-1 for "A" and 1e-3 for "B"

From one side it seems strange that 200K samples will be "solved" in 2 epochs..but if the results are the same on the graph, what is the difference? Should I prefer the longer run?

I've seen questions like:
[Keras : Should I care about the LAST epoch val_acc or only the HIGHEST epoch val_acc?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260554/keras-should-i-care-about-the-last-epoch-val-acc-or-only-the-highest-epoch-val)

but I don't feel the answer there helped me.

Comment: If the training accuracy is 0.99 at epoch 2 while validation accuracy is at 0.85, I'd suspect from overfitting. Then, it makes sense it to stay the same at later epochs since it already memorized the training dataset.

Comment: To clarify: training acc reaches 0.99 and training loss reaches 0.1 for "A" after 2 epochs and for "B" after 600